# Returning a string value after array.find() is throwing a Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: reactjs, return

In code snippet below, `console.log(el.distance)` is equal to a `string`.
For one reason or the other, if I try to `return` `el.distance` react keeps throwing me the classic:

`Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {item, distance}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

```
  return evtsFiltered?.map((item) => {
    return (
      <div>
        Distance:
        {distance?.find((el) => {
          if (el.item === item._id) console.log(el.distance)
        })}
      </div>
    )
  })
```

How can?

I also tried putting it between html tags like so

```
return evtsFiltered?.map((item) => {
    return (
      <div>
        Distance:
        {distance?.find((el) => {
          if (el.item === item._id) return <p> {el.distance} </p>
        })}
      </div>
    )
  })
```

Nothing works, please help!

Comment: are all of the elements in your array strings or maybe some are objects ? can you paste your console.log of el.distance here?

Comment: the result are the following: `18.2` and `0.7`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) returns an object from an array that satisfy the testing function. Result of [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) can't simply be a string if the array is of type objects.

You should be doing something like this

```
{distance?.find((el) => el.item === item._id)?.distance}
```

Comment: We have a winner. Thanks Sohaib. But why does my console.log returns a string ?

Comment: `console.log` only prints it to the console. `distance?.find` returns `undefined` in that case. That is the reason you only see console log but nothing rendered on the page.

Comment: You can go through this short tutorial https://www.javascripttutorial.net/es6/javascript-array-find/

Answer (score -1):

As you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the function `.find` return the first value found by the callback. It is differente from a map, that will return anything you return in the callback funcion
Instead of this:

```
    {distance?.find((el) => {
      if (el.item === item._id) return <p> {el.distance} </p>
    })}
```

You can try this:

```
<p>
   {distance?.find((el) => {
      if (el.item === item._id) return {el.distance} 
    })}
</p>
```

Comment: Allready tried, now tried again, same problem